# Selectively make one section of axis line thicker in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a density plot using ggplot2, and make one section of the x-axis line thicker (or colored differently).

For example:

```
interval <- c(x1,x2)
x <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + geom_density()
```

Is there any way to selectively make the x-axis segment corresponding to (x1,x2) thicker or colored differently? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to add a line segment. Setting the y coordinates to `-Inf` will place it on the x axis. Since your example isn't reproducible, I've demonstrated on the `mtcars` data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  annotate(
    geom = "segment",
    x = 3, xend = 4,
    y = -Inf, yend = -Inf,
    color = "blue",
    size = 5
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want to do.